# windows Chrome zoomed in displays half screen

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

The webapp displays half screen vertically when chrome on windows is zoomed in. I was able to fix it for when chrome is zoomed into 150% by adding margin 1px. But, its not fixed for 110% zoomed or other combinations. I am having tough time figuring out the right fix in css or javascript or jquery. The issue seems to be coming from style .ui-mobile-viewport with margin 0 coming from jquery.mobile-1.4.1.css. Appreciate your time and help.

#### chrome zoomed in displays partial/half screen:

[image: chrome zoomed in displays partial/half screen]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you include the relevant code so we can assist you more effectively?

Answer (score 0):

I have set the margin to 5px and it worked fine dbut a vertical scroll bar is showing up on windows chrome where the screen content was longer than the screen height.

Comment: I am still looking for the correct and long term solution to avoid this problem in any scaling